# SpriteKit- How do you check for intersections between SKNodes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm testing out a very basic project, and I can't seem to get the `intersectsNode` function working. In my GameScene.swift file, I created an `SKShapeNode` called world, and inside it, another `SKShapeNode` called `player` and a spinning `SKShapeNode` called `spinningGreenSquare`.

In my GameViewController.swift file, I setup a `touchesMoved` function that finds the location of the touch, `location`, and moves the `player` to it. Now, as you'll see in the below image, I then test if the 2 intersect, and preform some actions if the return value is true. When I run my project though, the `player` moves around just fine, but the intersection test always turns up `false, even though they are clearly intersecting on the device. Below is my code for the project. Is my declaration of something incorrect, or am I not using intersections properly?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
var touchedInPlayer = false

func goto(target: String) {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(target) as! UINavigationController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let location = touches.first!.locationInNode(scene!.player)
    let locationInWorld = touches.first!.locationInNode(scene!.world)
    if location.x < 25 && location.x > -25 && location.y < 25 && location.y > -25 {
        touchedInPlayer = true
        scene!.player.position = locationInWorld
    }

}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    //finds the location of the touch
    let location = touches.first!.locationInNode(scene!.world)

    //tests if the touch was in the player's square and moves the player to touch
    if scene!.player.containsPoint(location) {
        scene!.player.position = location
    }

    //what should happen when the 2 squares intersect
    if scene!.player.intersectsNode(scene!.spinningGreenSquare) {

        goto("Another View")
    }

}
```

}

[****Link For My Code****](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t372.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `update:` function instead of `touchesMoved:` by using this code:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if scene!.player.intersectsNode(scene!.spinningGreenSquare) {

        goto("Another View")
    }

}
```

Another thing you should try is making sure Player and SpinningGreenSquare are both of type `SKSpriteNode`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I changed them to `SpriteNode`'s and it ran like a charm.